# pandoc can't convert tables from markdown to epub in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, markdown, pandoc, epub

pandoc can't convert a tables from markdown to epub3 in ubuntu.
I tryed table formats.
(simple_tables, multiline_tables, and pipe_tables of php/emacs variation with enable option)
and convert table to PDF is working fine.

## Steps of reproduction

```
sudo apt install -y pandoc texlive
git clone https://github.com/MichinariNukazawa/pandoc-book-template
# base repo https://github.com/wikiti/pandoc-book-template
#  is old and already pull requested
cd pandoc-book-template
make
```

Comment: Where’s your sample input? What’s the actual output?

Comment: the pandoc version in `apt` is usually quite old: see http://pandoc.org/installing.html